# Serializing, compressing and writing large object to file in one go takes too much memory

Tags: python, dill, brotli

I have a list of very large objects `objects`, that I want to compress and save to the hard drive.

My current approach is

```
import brotli
import dill
# serialize list of objects
objects_serialized = dill.dumps(objects, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
# compress serialized string
objects_serialized_compressed = brotli.compress(data=objects_serialized, quality=1)
# write compressed string to file
output.write(objects_serialized_compressed)
```

However, if `objects` is very large, this leads to a memory error, since -- for some time -- I simultaneously carry `objects`, `objects_serialized`, `objects_serialized_compressed` around in their entirety.

Is there a way to do this chunk-wise? Presumably the first step -- serializing the objects -- has to done in one go, but perhaps the compression and writing to file can be done chunk-wise?

Comment: Try a memory buffer, or serialize by chunks.

Comment: @Memristor dill does not allow serialization by chunks -- at least, the resulting object is going to look different I think -- I would prefer an approach where the read() method does not to be aware of the changes I'm doing to the writing process now.

Comment: `brotli.compress(...)` has no `data` argument, at least for the version I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this, after many attemps:

```
import brotli
import dill
import io
import pickle

# The following serialized object is 30kb
objects = ["234r234r234", "3f234f2343f3", "234ff234f234f234rf32"]*5000
objects_serialized = dill.dumps(objects, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# Set up a buffer for reading chunks of serialized data
chunk_size = 1024 * 1024
buffer = io.BytesIO(objects_serialized)

# Create compressor for repeated use
compressor = brotli.Compressor(quality=1)
with open('output.brotli', 'wb') as output:
    # Read chunks from the buffer and compress them
    while True:
        chunk = buffer.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk:
            break
        compressed_chunk = compressor.process(chunk)
        output.write(compressed_chunk)

    # Flush the remaining compressed data
    compressed_remainder = compressor.finish()
    # 4kb in my computer
    # I decompressed, de-serialized, and retrieved the original object
    output.write(compressed_remainder)
```

---

This requires `brotli 1.0.9`, as provided by `pip` -- it does not work with `brotlipy`, as provided by anaconda.

Comment: I use (1.0.9), I think 0.7 has a `compress` method that is analogous but better check it.